# incompatible in Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone

I am developed one application. My xcode version is xcode 4.3.3. And I am using distribution certificate for appstore submission. And my ios development target is ios 3.0. At the time of archive I got the error like

> "this bundle is invalid. the key uirequireddevicecapabilities contains value armv7 ' which is incompatible with the minimumosversion value of '3.0'"

So please tell me how can I solve this one. And at the time of creating that distribution provisioning certificate I didn't add any device. So anybody know what is the reason please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

First the `ARMv7` error has to do with the fact that your `info.plist` key `uirequireddevicecapabilities` is set to `ARMv7`, but you target iOS 3.0 so Apple also want's you to support the `ARMv6`. Just remove the `ARMv7` from the `info.plist`.

If you set the distribution provisioning profile to AppStore you will not be able to add device since this provisioning profile is meant to upload a app for appstore review only.